# Why don't you delete my account?

Tags: support, status-completed

Please delete my History-beta account, as per my several unanswered requests.

Why don't you delete my account? I have already requested **twice**.

Comment: Deleted my answer. It was wrong, as I did not understand how StackExchange works. I sincerely apologize to you for your perceived personal insults from me to you. It was honestly not intended to be personal. (Even though I used the word your, I intended your to mean anyone). My deepest apologies.

Comment: @CGCampbell - NP.